# generate DDL from JPA annotations

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, maven-2

I have the following classes in my JPA model (getters, setters, and irrelevant fields omitted):

```
@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@IdClass(PricePK.class)
public class Price {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Product product;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Currency currency;
}

@Embeddable
public class PricePK implements Serializable {

    Integer product;        
    Integer currency;
}

@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Currency extends PersistentEntity {

    @Id
    private Integer ix;
}

@Entity @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Product extends AutoIdPersistentEntity {
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AutoIdPersistentEntity extends PersistentEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

I use the [hbm2ddl](http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-hibernate3/hibernate3-maven-plugin/hbm2ddl-mojo.html) goal of the hibernate3 Maven plugin to generate a DDL from these classes. It generates the following for the table corresponding to the `Price` class

```
create table PRICE (
    currency_id int null,
    product_id int null,
    primary key (currency_id, product_id)
);
```

Notice that both `currency_id` and `product_id` are nullable, which causes the following error when I try to load the DDL into SQL Server

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'PRICE'

I don't understand why these are nullable, because in the domain model they are annotated 
`@ManyToOne(optional = false)`

The DDL is generated using the `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect` SQL dialect.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing but I think the optional attribute (@ManyToOne, @Basic,...) is not used for schema generation by some JPA implementations.

I think you need to use the @JoinColumn annotation and set nullable to false:
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html

(Or @Column in non-join cases: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Column.html)